# Boost Asio SerialPort. Can't create serial port service and open it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm trying to get data from serial port using `boost::asio::serialport`.
I've got some problem when i'm creating object serial port. The problem is that this code is thrown with error that showed on image

> "An unhandled exception occurred at 0x75901932 in ASIO_test.exe"

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service *is1 = new boost::asio::io_service();
    const std::string Port = {"COM5"};
    boost::asio::serial_port sp1(*is1, Port);
    return 0;
}
```

[Exeption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nabLY.png)

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

A little diving into the root of this problem reveal some details: program getting the error when trying to open port with GetCommState from "win_iocp_serial_port_service.ipp" line 73.
GetCommState is the function from WinBase.h